# SQL Server Standard installation error: Login failed. The Login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have been getting this error when trying to install SQL server 2017 standard. I am installing this on a newly formatted system too. The network is set to private, I'm not sure if that matters.

I started the installation as Administrator as well, then added the current user to the list of SQL system administrators and I keep getting this error. I even reformatted this computer and I keep getting the same error.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this? The system is not under any domain policies either.

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: "I started the installation as Administrator as well, then added the current user" what current user (Administrator)? Does the installation proceed if you use the option to use only SQL Server login?

Comment: Are you running the install as a local or domain user? Are you using a service account that is a domain user? Is the computer joined to the domain?

Comment: @Ronaldo The current user is an Administrator. Picking only SQL login (no mixed mode) also results in the same error

Comment: @AMtwo I am running the install as a local Admin user in windows. The computer is not connected to a domain, for good measure I even tried to disconnect the network cable and run the install. Which did not make a difference

Comment: Could you try downloading and installing a different version of SQL Server (like 2016 express) just to check if it's related to the media you're using? What is your O.S.? What options have you chosen through the installation process?

Comment: Verbose install logs will be located at `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log\<YYYYMMDD_HHMM>\` . The contents of the install log should help identify the issue. You may need to upload it as a [gist](https://gist.github.com) or similar and add the link to that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the culprit. The name of the computer was set to a string that was higher than the limit that windows allows. I changed the name of the computer to something else within the allowed limit and I was able to install the server successfully.